# How can I replace all duplicated paths of a url with a JS Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For the following URL:
https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world

I want to replace all the occurrences of "/test/", and its important that it "test" starts with and ends with a "/".

I tried with:

```
let url = "https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world"
url.replace(/\/test\//g, "/");
```

But it returns:
'https://www.google.es/test/hello/world'

It doesn't replace the second "/test/"

Any clues on how I could do this with a regex?

I basically want to replace the content that lives inside the dashes, but not the dashes themselves.

Comment: Use: `url.replace(/\/test(?=\/)/g, "/");`

Comment: So you want `"https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world"` to become `"https://www.google.es/hello/world"`?

Comment: @anubhava that seems to do the trick! Thanks :D

Comment: @BenAston depends, in the given example we could say that yes, however I would like to make it so that you can also replace it for other paths.
Would it be possible to detect if both occurrences are next to each other so that for instance, instead of replacing test every time, it just does it once (with a regex)?
Example:
from: https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world
to: https://www.google.es/WORKS/hello/world
where "test" was replaced for "WORKS"

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74029968/how-can-i-replace-all-duplicated-paths-of-a-url-with-a-js-regex?noredirect=1#comment130742482_74029968) @Meir That's a different question (_How to replace only duplicated and contiguous values in a list?_). Feel free to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it if you can't find an existing question about it on this site.

Comment: @Meir: Posted an answer below to address these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on conversation in comment, you can use this solution:

```js
let url = "https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world"
console.log( url.replace(/(?:\/test)+(?=\/)/g, "/WORKS") );
//=> https://www.google.es/WORKS/hello/world
```

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `(?:\/test)+`: Match 1+ repeats of text `/test`
- `(?=\/)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a `/` ahead

Comment: Thanks so much, There are some trigger happy people :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
/(\/[^\/]+)(?:\1)+\//g
```

- `(` - open capture group #1

  - `\/` - find a literal slash
  - `[^\/]+` - capture at least one non-slash char
- `)` - close capture group #1
- `(?:\1)+` - repeat capture group #1 one or more times
- `\/` - ensure a closing slash
- `/g` - global modifier

https://regex101.com/r/NgJA3X/1

```js
var regex = /(\/[^\/]+)(?:\1)+\//g;

var str = `https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world
https://www.google.es/test/test/test/test/hello/world
https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/test/hello/hello/world
https://www.google.es/test/hello/world/world
https://www.google.es/test/hello/helloworld/world`;
var subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
var result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can** do this with a regular expression, but it sounds like your intent is to replace only individual parts of the [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) component of a URL.

A URL has other components (such as the [fragment identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash)) which could contain the pattern that you describe, and handling that distinction with a regular expression is more challenging.

The [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class is designed to help solve problems just like this, and you can replace just the path parts using a functional technique like this:

```js
function replacePathParts (url, targetStr, replaceStr = '') {
  url = new URL(url);
  const updatedPathname = url.pathname
    .split('/')
    .map(str => str === targetStr ? replaceStr : str)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join('/');
  url.pathname = updatedPathname;
  return url.href;
}

const inputUrl = 'https://www.google.es/test/test/hello/world';

const result1 = replacePathParts(inputUrl, 'test');
console.log(result1); // "https://www.google.es/hello/world"

const result2 = replacePathParts(inputUrl, 'test', 'message');
console.log(result2); // "https://www.google.es/message/message/hello/world"
```